# Hazelcast MapStrore#store()

Tags: java, hazelcast

When changing the object put to the MapStore, it doesn't seem to accept my changes (setting mysql db id on persistance). The change made does not appear in the object when checked out later on. That means to me, that the store method call is an additional call after the serialization.
Do I have to put the object to the hazelcast map once more?

Comment: Is your map store enabled? And what is the write delay... can you post your hazelcast config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that currently in Hazelcast the serialization of the value is done before the database interaction is done. So no matter what you do in your mapstore, it will not be visible in the serialized content. So your conclusion is correct.

Combining the mapstore with database generated id's or optimistic locking using a version field currently is a PITA. This is an issue we are looking at for some other customers and hope to provide a solution ASAP.

Comment: Enes, our man in charge of the map, just started on the issue.

So it will be part of Hazelcast 3.2.

Comment: suggested ways around it?)

Comment: Workaround what I am currently using is, to implement the PostProcessingMapStore interface. Although this entails an additional serialization process.